# useState adds last saved array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, web

I am working on this todo list app with React, and I noticed, how when I add a Todo to the Todos array, the array adds the last "inputed" data. So for example, if I enter one Todo, the Todos array will push and empty array, and then if I press submit again, it will push the first thing I entered, and so on. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
const TodoInput = ({ todos, setTodos }) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmitEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodo({
      text: input,
      id: uuid(),
    });
    addTodoToList();
    setInput("");
  };
  const addTodoToList = () => {
    setTodos((todos) => [...todos, todo]);
  };

  const updateInput = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form className="TodoInput" onSubmit={handleSubmitEvent}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="New Item"
        onChange={updateInput}
        value={input}
      />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Setting the state, for example `setTodo` is async. This is means that `todo` is not update before you call `addTodoToList`. Like in the duplicate answer, the `todo` state is redundant. Just add the current input directly to the `todos` - `setTodos((todos) => [...todos, { text: input, id: uuid() }]);`